# Undefined variable $names

Tags: laravel-livewire

The rest of the blade files are reading values from the controller well. The ..layout/app.blade file is getting undefined variable $names from ..Layout/App.php.

Below is my App.php. I have tried to dd($names) seems its the App.php is not being reached.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Layouts;

use Livewire\Component;

class App extends Component
{

    public $names ="Alex Boey";

    public function mount(){
        dd($this->names);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.layouts.app');
    }
}
```

app.blade.php

```
    <head>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>

<div>{{$names}}</div>

{{ $slot }}

@livewireScripts
</body>
```

[View Image to see the files on IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2UBQ.png)

Comment: add `<div>{{$names}}</div>` into `'livewire.layouts.app'` view then in `layout/app.blade.php` insert `<livewire:app />`

Comment: I have done that still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Livewire component can only have a [single root element](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#returning-blade). You're using Livewire to load in the full app view. That simply won't work.

lostika already provided the answer you're looking for;

Replace the `<div>{{$names}}</div>` in your app.blade with `<livewire:layouts.app/>`, and then inside the view of your Livewire component:

```html
<div>
    {{$names}}
</div>
```

If the app.blade that you posted is the same as your Livewire component's view, then you need to move that to a separate, non-Livewire location.